# How to exclude modules or groups in a jar from Gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to write a gradle script where i want to ignore or exclude certain modules or groups from a jar file.

My Code :

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])     
    compile files('libs/test.jar')

  }
```

So , from test.jar file i want to exclude 'com.xyz.abc' , but i don't find how do i write the script.

Please let me know , suggest me some good solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try excluding transitive dependencies as described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html):

You can exclude a transitive dependency either by configuration or by dependency:

Example 52.14. Excluding transitive dependencies

build.gradle

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'commons'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.gradle.test.excludes', module: 'reports'
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.gradle.test.excludes:api:1.0") {
        exclude module: 'shared'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what , i was looking for. Thanks again

Comment: I'm trying to use exclude() myself, but with compile files:  compile files ('libs/sshd-core-0.7.0.jar') {  exclude module: 'mina-core'  }.  However, I just can't make it work.  Does exclude not work when compiling a jar??

Comment: @Rich so did you manage to find a solution? I also came here with the same intent of yours.

Comment: @GuilhermeSantos Did you find a solution?

Comment: exclude can not work with the `compile files` or  `compile fileTree`, maybe we can unzip the jar file, delete it, then compress into new pure jar ~

Comment: Thanks finally removing the class file worked for me.