# How to exclude a dependency from a local library in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, build.gradle

```
implementation files("libs/Somelib.jar") {
        exclude(group = 'com.example.mypackage', module = 'somelib-ex')
    }
```

Wanted to exclude

Cannot set the value of read-only property 'module' for project ':android-aw-network-library' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 0):

According to gradle documentation:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps

```
dependencies {
implementation('commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4') {
    exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
}
```

Comment: yes, but can I do this with a local library. ?

Comment: You can check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671005/how-to-exclude-modules-or-groups-in-a-jar-from-gradle